# Cocoa user can set screen size

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm completely new to Cocoa and Xcode. I started using it a couple of days ago, because I have to build a little tool for macOS.

After hours of research I still can't find a solution for my problem.

What I need to do:

- A window with a Quartz Composer Patch QCView (everything working) which resizes with the window the QCView is in
- There should be a second window with two text fields (with Number Formatter and editable).
- Those text fields should show the current resolution of the window with the QCView
- The user should also be able to type numbers in the text fields to set the size of the QCView (x and y)

As I mentioned above, I'm not really experienced in Cocoa, Xcode, Objective-C or Swift.
If someone could give me some hints how to accomplish those tasks would be great (especially with which parts of the code have to be put in the .h and .m  or .swift files).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are trying to build Rome overnight.  Everyone here was once a beginner just as you are.  Instead of jumping on to something gigantic, build something that is attainable and move up little by little.

Comment: Wenn I know that this task is quite complex. Usually I try to learn stuff as you said (python for example). But my employer just told me to build an app like this using Xcode and he doesn't have the time / money to let me spend weeks to learn everything from the beginning. I had the hope there would be some "easy" way to let the user set the screen size..